# sorting the characters of a string in ascending order using merge sort + java

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to sort the characters of a string in ascending order using the merge sort, but I don't know where exactly should I compare the characters in order to sort them.
this is my method so far:

```
public static String mergeSort(String s)
    {
        String left = "",
               right = "";
        if(s.length() <= 1)
            return s;
        int middle = s.length()/2;
        for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
            left = left + s.charAt(i);
        for(int i = middle+1; i < s.length(); i++)
            right = right + s.charAt(i);
        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);
        return merge(left, right);
    }
```

I'll be glad if you help me 
thanks

Comment: Where's the `merge()` method?

Comment: I haven't still coded the merge method. I thought I have to finish this one first. don't I?

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you read [Wikipedia's entry on MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Two things to suggest based on your code

1. The actual comparison of two characters does not happen in `mergeSort()` but rather in `merge()`. See Wikipedia's pseudocode to learn how to write it.
2. I do not recommend you build the `left` and `right` String objects reading one character at a time. No need to use `charAt()`. Instead, use `String.substring()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

#### ADDITIONAL INFO

Use this to set `left` and `right`:

```
String left = s.substring(0, middle);
String right = s.substring(middle);
```

Comment: so you mean that I change the "left = left + s.charAt(i);" to "left = s.substring(i);"

Comment: thanks, I did the same thing before you tell me your additional info ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subtraction of the two characters. So if you have two chars `a` and `b` and:

- `a - b = 0`, characters are equal
- `a - b > 0`, `a` is greater
- `a - b < 0`, `b` is greater

This is exactly how the `Character.compareTo()` method has been implemented.

Comment: can you tell me where exactly should I compare the characters? in this method? where exactly in it? in the for?

Comment: This should be in the `merge` method. Have you already implemented one? If yes, it'll be helpful if you show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `String` in your computations, since `String` in Java is immutable. You will create thousands of objects, which will slow down your implementation. I would suggest using `char[]` instead.
2. You do the actual comparison in your `merge()` subroutine. You compare `char` in the same way you  compare for example `int`, just with standard `>` operator.

Comment: 1. actually in the specifications given, it is written that the output should be a string an also it should be sorted (in this method and not in the merge one)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the input string to a character array and do the computation for merge sort as shown below:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void sort(char[] chars, int low, int right) {
        if (low < right) {
            int middle = (low + right) / 2;
            sort(chars, low, middle);
            sort(chars, middle + 1, right);
            merge(chars, low, middle, right);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(char[] chars, int low, int middle, int right) {
        Queue<Character> queue1 = new LinkedList<Character>();
        Queue<Character> queue2 = new LinkedList<Character>();

        for (int i = low; i <= middle; i++) {
            queue1.add(chars[i]);
        } 

        for (int i = middle + 1; i <= right; i++) {
            queue2.add(chars[i]);
        }

        int i = low;

        while (!queue1.isEmpty() && !queue2.isEmpty()) {
            if (queue1.peek() <= queue2.peek()) {
                chars[i++] = queue1.poll();
            } else {
                chars[i++] = queue2.poll();
            }
        }

        while (!queue1.isEmpty()) {
            chars[i++] = queue1.poll();
        }

        while (!queue2.isEmpty()) {
            chars[i++] = queue2.poll();
        }
    }

    public static void sort(char[] chars) {
        sort(chars, 0, chars.length - 1);
    }

    public static void sort(String string) {
        sort(string.toCharArray());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "sarathkumarsivan";
        char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

        MergeSort.sort(chars);

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) { System.out.print(", "); }
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
        }
    }
}
```